# Random Chrome Notifications and Strange Source Code

Tags: malware, web-browser, javascript, chrome, macos

My elderly parents are receiving chrome notifications from a strange URL on their iMac: 
(https://s1.snc.com.ru:443)

**Example Messages**

• Pending Payment: Paypal Has Sent You $65,900

• Clean your mac. Do not ignore this message.

[image: Screenshot of Notifications]

I've remotely connected and scanned with Malwarebytes & Avast, but have found no threats.

I didn't see any issues when checking the URL on VirusTotal either. Visiting the URL renders a progress bar made with Bootstrap/Javascript and asks for permission to give notifications. Of course, I click no/block. There's some interesting javascript in the sourcecode that has a couple other URLS.

I've just blocked the notifications for now, but I'm really curious; what is this? Did I screw up by visiting the URL?

Comment: You may want to check the installed extensions/add-ons in the browser. Also maybe check that they don't have an alternate DNS setting in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site asks permission to send [Web Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/). That's not technically a malware and won't get detected as such. The site is just using this permission in a malicious way by sending these spam messages. That's pretty common.

- Malwarebytes: [Browser push notifications: a feature asking to be abused](https://blog.malwarebytes.com/security-world/technology/2019/01/browser-push-notifications-feature-asking-abused/)
- [Sites Trick Users Into Subscribing to Browser Notification Spam](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/sites-trick-users-into-subscribing-to-browser-notification-spam/)

  > To remove them in Chrome, you can go into the Settings and search for
  >   **Notifications**, click on **Content Settings**, and then click on
  >   **Notifications**. Chrome will now display a list of sites that you are
  >   subscribed to or have blocked.

You must teach your parents some basic rules on the Internet: Don't click *yes* on everything. By default, select *no* if you don't understand the question. You could also tweak their browser to help them with this task:

- Disabled web push notifications altogether by selecting *Do not allow any site to show notifications* from the Content Settings.
- You could also disable location by selecting *Do not allow any site to track your physical location*.
- Revise all Content Settings and disable everything your parents won't actually need.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input and the articles. Very helpful!